# How to use Django Bulk Add to Database Feature

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I am trying to add around 40-50k rows to pgsql Database from Django from a Text File Dump from an Application for Data Processing

Following is my Function

```
def populate_backup_db(dumpfile):
    sensordata=sensorrecords()  **** This is the Model
    start_time = time.time()
    file= open(dumpfile)
    filedata = file.readlines()
    endcount=len(filedata)
    i=0
    imagecount=0
    while i<endcount:
        lineitem = split_entry(filedata[i])
        if (lineitem[0]== "HEADER"):
            imagecount=imagecount+1
            sensordata.Sensor          = lineitem[1]
            sensordata.Date1           = lineitem[2]
            sensordata.Date2           = lineitem[3]
            sensordata.Version         = lineitem[4]  
            sensordata.Proxyclient     = lineitem[8]
            sensordata.Triggerdate     = ctodatetime(lineitem[13])
            sensordata.Compression     = lineitem[16]
            sensordata.Encryption      = lineitem[17]
            sensordata.Fragments       = lineitem[21]
            sensordata.Pbit            = lineitem[37]
            sensordata.BlockIntFT      = lineitem[38]
            sensordata.OriginServer   =  lineitem[56]
            sensordata.save()
        i=i+1
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(imagecount ,'entries saved to database from ',dumpfile,'. Time Taken is ',elapsed_time,' seconds.')
    file.close()
```

This is taking around 2-3 minutes to save all data to Database. 
This Dumpfile is likely to Increase in size, and if this Function is to be used, It can take a couple of minutes to Save All data to Database

How can I fetch all Data from Dump File and then save it all to the Database in single go.

I see a DJANGO Method called bulk_create()

```
bulk_create()¶

    bulk_create(objs, batch_size=None, ignore_conflicts=False)¶
```

This method inserts the provided list of objects into the database in an efficient manner (generally only 1 query, no matter how many objects there are):

```
>>> Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
...     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
... ])
```

The Example seems to be adding entries Manually , The Function I am using is running a loop until all entries are fetched , saving the in the process.

How Do I run it in Loop ? Do I replace `sensordata.save()` with `some_list.append(sensordata)`

and in the end after the loop ends, do a

```
sensordata.objects.bulk_create(some_list)
```

I edited my Code to Append the Object to a List and then do a Bulk Update in the end as below

```
def populate_backup_db(dumpfile):
    sensordata=sensorrecords()  **** This is the Model
    datalist =[]
    start_time = time.time()
    file= open(dumpfile)
    filedata = file.readlines()
    endcount=len(filedata)
    i=0
    imagecount=0
    while i<endcount:
        lineitem = split_entry(filedata[i])
        if (lineitem[0]== "HEADER"):
            imagecount=imagecount+1
            sensordata.Sensor          = lineitem[1]
            sensordata.Date1           = lineitem[2]
            sensordata.Date2           = lineitem[3]
            sensordata.Version         = lineitem[4]  
            sensordata.Proxyclient     = lineitem[8]
            sensordata.Triggerdate     = ctodatetime(lineitem[13])
            sensordata.Compression     = lineitem[16]
            sensordata.Encryption      = lineitem[17]
            sensordata.Fragments       = lineitem[21]
            sensordata.Pbit            = lineitem[37]
            sensordata.BlockIntFT      = lineitem[38]
            sensordata.OriginServer   =  lineitem[56]
            datalist.append(sensordata)
        i=i+1
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(imagecount ,'entries saved to database from ',dumpfile,'. Time Taken is ',elapsed_time,' seconds.')
sensordata.objects.bulk_create(datalist)    
file.close()
```

This throws an error below

Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\va\eclipse-workspace\prod\home\views.py" in process_data
  68.             get_backup_data()

File "C:\Users\va\eclipse-workspace\prod\home\process.py" in get_backup_data
  8.     populate_backup_db('c:\\users\\va\\desktop\\vsp\\backupdata_server.txt')

File "C:\Users\va\eclipse-workspace\prod\home\process.py" in populate_backup_db
  122.     sensordata.objects.bulk_create(datalist)

File "C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in __get__
  176.             raise AttributeError("Manager isn't accessible via %s instances" % cls.__name__)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /process_data/
Exception Value: Manager isn't accessible via sensorrecords instances
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like this:

```
def populate_backup_db(dumpfile):
    datalist =[]
    start_time = time.time()
    file= open(dumpfile)
    filedata = file.readlines()
    endcount=len(filedata)
    i=0
    imagecount=0
    while i<endcount:
        lineitem = split_entry(filedata[i])
        if (lineitem[0]== "HEADER"):
            imagecount=imagecount+1
            sensordata = sensorrecords()  # initiating object here
            sensordata.Sensor          = lineitem[1]
            sensordata.Date1           = lineitem[2]
            sensordata.Date2           = lineitem[3]
            sensordata.Version         = lineitem[4]  
            sensordata.Proxyclient     = lineitem[8]
            sensordata.Triggerdate     = ctodatetime(lineitem[13])
            sensordata.Compression     = lineitem[16]
            sensordata.Encryption      = lineitem[17]
            sensordata.Fragments       = lineitem[21]
            sensordata.Pbit            = lineitem[37]
            sensordata.BlockIntFT      = lineitem[38]
            sensordata.OriginServer   =  lineitem[56]
            datalist.append(sensordata)
        i=i+1
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(imagecount ,'entries saved to database from ',dumpfile,'. Time Taken is ',elapsed_time,' seconds.')
    sensorrecords.objects.bulk_create(datalilist) # you need to access objects method via model class name   
    file.close()
```

Comment: This Worked !!! Not Sure if there was any Document mentioning this has to be referenced by Class Name.